Example of a tripotent element of a ring which is not an idempotent
Let $R$ be a ring. An element $e\in R$ is said to be idempotent if $e^2=e$ and an element $t$ is said to be tripotent if $t^3=t$. It is clear that every idempotent is tripotent because if $e^2=e$ then $e^3=e^2=e$. But is there an element which is tripotent but not idempotent?

$-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and more generally, any ring with unity that is not of characteristic $2$.

$4$ in $\mathbb{Z_{30}}$ is tripotent but not idempotent.

Simpler: already true in its image $,\Bbb Z_5,$ since there $, 4 = -1\ \ $

Indeed, as Bill notes, this example is of the more general flavor. For any product of rings $S := \prod_{i \in I} R_{i}$, and any collection $e = (e_{i}){i\in I} \in S$ such that $e{j}$ is tripotent but not idempotent for some fixed $j \in J$ and all other $e_{i}$s are either tripotent, then $e$ is tripotent but not idempotent. Via the Chinese Remainder Theorem, your example is just the element $(0, 1, -1) \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

@AlexWertheim:  did you mean either tripotent or idempotent?

and did you mean $j\in I$?

@J.W.Tanner yes, I should have written $j \in I$, thanks. And the comment should just read "...$e_{i}$s are tripotent". Originally, the comment said "are either tripotent or idempotent", since I had thought the definition of tripotent included not being idempotent, but then I reread the OP and edited it to what you see now. Thanks to the 5 min time limit, I can't edit it anymore... oh well.

The element $2\in\mathbb{F_3}$ satisfies that.

Here $,2=-1.,$ Generally $-1$ is tripotent in  every ring, but is idempotent $!\iff! 2=0.\ \ $

$$\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}^{\large2}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\text{ and } \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}^{\large3}=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}.$$

i.e. any $\rm\color{#c00}{nontrivial}$ reflection (involution) works: $,f^2 = 1\color{#c00}{\neq f}\Rightarrow f^3 = f\ \ $
